# Filter an array using multiple selection options

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dom

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and I'm trying to filter an array of vehicles, using dropdown menus, the first filter shows it by brand name, then the second filter by type of vehicle.
Filters seem to work just fine but when I select a brand and then a type it shows me all the array of items using the type filter, and ignores the brand filter

**Array:**

```
const Data = [
  {
    brand: "Volkswagen",
    type: "Car",
    model: "Golf",
    year: "2019",
    price: "$12,000",
  },
  {
    brand: "Volkswagen",
    type: "Truck",
    model: "Tiguan",
    year: "2020",
    price: "$20,000",
  },
  {
    brand: "Mazda",
    type: "Car",
    model: "Mazda 3",
    year: "2022",
    price: "$32,000",
  },
  {
    brand: "Mazda",
    type: "Truck",
    model: "Mazda 6",
    year: "2021",
    price: "$29,000",
  },
  {
    brand: "Tesla",
    type: "Car",
    model: "Model S",
    year: "2023",
    price: "$42,000",
  },
  {
    brand: "Tesla",
    type: "Truck",
    model: "Model X",
    year: "2020",
    price: "$50,000",
  },
];
```

**Functions:**

```
const getSelectedValue = () => {
  let brandSelection = document.getElementById("brandDropdown").value;
  let selection = document.getElementById("dropDownSelection");
  //   show all cars
  if (brandSelection === "All") {
    selection.innerHTML = "";
    Data.forEach((car) => {
      selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
            <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
            <p>${car.type}</p>
            <p>${car.model}</p>
            <p>${car.year}</p>
            <p>${car.price}</p>
        </div>`;
    });
  }
  //   show selected brand
  else {
    selection.innerHTML = "";
    Data.forEach((car) => {
      if (car.brand === brandSelection) {
        selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                <p>${car.type}</p>
                <p>${car.model}</p>
                <p>${car.year}</p>
                <p>${car.price}</p>
            </div>`;
      }
    });
  }

  console.log(brandSelection);
};

// filter by type when brand is selected

const getSelectedType = () => {
  let typeSelection = document.getElementById("typeDropdown").value;
  let selection = document.getElementById("dropDownSelection");
  //   show all cars
  if (typeSelection === "All") {
    selection.innerHTML = "";
    Data.forEach((car) => {
      selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                <p>${car.type}</p>
                <p>${car.model}</p>
                <p>${car.year}</p>
                <p>${car.price}</p>
            </div>`;
    });
  }
  //   show selected type
  else {
    selection.innerHTML = "";
    Data.forEach((car) => {
      if (car.type === typeSelection) {
        selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                    <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                    <p>${car.type}</p>
                    <p>${car.model}</p>
                    <p>${car.year}</p>
                    <p>${car.price}</p>
                </div>`;
      }
    });
  }

  console.log(typeSelection);
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

    <div class="dropDown">
        <div class="Brand">
            <select name="" id="brandDropdown" onchange="getSelectedValue()">
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
                <option value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="Type">
            <select name="" id="typeDropdown" onchange="getSelectedType()">
                <option value="">Type</option>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Car">Car</option>
                <option value="Truck">Truck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="" id="dropDownSelection">

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look on this code

```js
// JAVASCRIPT

....

const getSelected = () => {
  let typeSelection = document.getElementById('typeDropdown').value;
  let brandSelection = document.getElementById('brandDropdown').value;
  let selection = document.getElementById('dropDownSelection');
  // Show all cars
  if (brandSelection === 'All' && typeSelection === 'All') {
    selection.innerHTML = '';
    Data.forEach((car) => {
      selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                <p>${car.type}</p>
                <p>${car.model}</p>
                <p>${car.year}</p>
                <p>${car.price}</p>
            </div>`;
    });
  }
  // Show selected brand
  else if (brandSelection !== 'All' && typeSelection === 'All') {
    selection.innerHTML = '';
    Data.filter((car) => car.brand === brandSelection).forEach((car) => {
      selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                <p>${car.type}</p>
                <p>${car.model}</p>
                <p>${car.year}</p>
                <p>${car.price}</p>
            </div>`;
    });
  // Show selected type
  } else if (brandSelection === 'All' && typeSelection !== 'All') {
    selection.innerHTML = '';
    Data.filter((car) => car.type === typeSelection).forEach((car) => {
      selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                <p>${car.type}</p>
                <p>${car.model}</p>
                <p>${car.year}</p>
                <p>${car.price}</p>
            </div>`;
    });
  // show selected brand and type
  } else {
    selection.innerHTML = '';
    Data.filter(
      (car) => car.brand === brandSelection && car.type === typeSelection,
    ).forEach((car) => {
      selection.innerHTML += `<div class="car">
                <h3>${car.brand}</h3>
                <p>${car.type}</p>
                <p>${car.model}</p>
                <p>${car.year}</p>
                <p>${car.price}</p>
            </div>`;
    });
  }
};

....
```

```html
// HTML

....

<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="Brand">
    <select name="" id="brandDropdown" onchange="getSelected()">
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
      <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
      <option value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Type">
    <select name="" id="typeDropdown" onchange="getSelected()">
      <option value="">Type</option>
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="Car">Car</option>
      <option value="Truck">Truck</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

....
```

As you can see the 2 dropdown list only call one function getSelected(), it because if you do 2 filters you must combine them with each other not separated into 2  functions. i hope this will help thank you